# WinRT - change value of Flyout Setter programatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows store app project i have a Flyout, with a certain style

```
<Flyout>

...

      <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Enabled"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="300"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300"/>
                    <Setter x:Name="FlyMargin" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
        </Flyout>
```

Im trying to change the margin programatically in code behind, but so far i failed

i tried like this:~

```
InfoFlyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter
    {
        Property = FlyoutPresenter.MarginProperty,
        Value = "50,0,0,0"
   });
```

it works the first time i call the flyout, but the second if gives a exception.
Also tried something like this but still doesn't work

```
InfoFlyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.ElementAt(6).SetValue(FlyoutPresenter.MarginProperty, "-28,125,0,0");
```

How can i change the Margin Setter in the code behind ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't add the same Setter multiple times.
I recommend you to move your XAML style to code behind completely, setting all properties and replacing the FlyoutPresenterStyleProperty:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(FlyoutPresenter));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FlyoutPresenter.MarginProperty, new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0)));
//style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FlyoutPresenter... //Do It For All Properties

YourElementName.Flyout.SetValue(Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyleProperty, style);
```

It works here.